# Take the time from the datetime and convert it into seconds?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am running SQL Server 2005.  Technically I know how to take the time from a tsql datetime.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond
```

The problem is that I have a datetime field and I need to essentially grab the time portion convert that to an integer specifically seconds.  Then I need to do a bunch of arithmetic on this integer that I won't discuss here.  I have searched on stackoverflow and haven't found a question that is specific to this question.  Any ideas?  I am really looking for best practices here, I am worried about creating a udf for this specific purpose as it completely throws the query optimizer out the window.

I have seen this webpage so please don't paste this. :

http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?171561-TSQL-Converting-HH-MM-SS-to-seconds

Comment: Not sure there's anyone who could cope with level of ridicule they'd receive here if they posted an answer that involved strings. :p

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) * 3600) +
(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) * 60) +
(DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: I need to convert all of my time into seconds.  I am aware of how to grab seconds from my date via datepart.

Comment: I was hoping there was a better way of doing this than that.  Ok thanks for your answers guys.

Comment: @UserSmith  I think this'll be the most straight-forward approach... an alternative would be to implement a CLR function to do the conversion, but that would likely be more complex and less efficient...

Answer (score 17):

Just my 2 cents ...another way of doing this

Edit: Added method for SQL Server 2005 (Thank you Michael)

for SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

for sql server 2005+

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())), GETDATE())
```

Comment: msdn says that its available in 2005 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Ah... the `datediff` is good, but the [`date` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) in the `convert` wasn't introduced until 2008...

Comment: oh did not know that just checked for datediff before posting.Thank you i am updating anwser

Answer (score 0):

The functions you want is DatePart

```
Declare @d DateTime
Select @d = GetDate()
Select (DatePart(HOUR, @d) * 3600) + (DatePart(MINUTE, @d) * 60) + DatePart(SECOND, @d)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, check where the parentheses are.

Comment: None needed, if you'd have said it in a review, I would have probably rewritten it to (h * 3600) + (m * 60) + s, just to make it clearer.